# Laravel 5 - ORM has() Relationship (Inverse - notHas)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In the Laravel 5 I can find all posts that have at least one comment using `has` method:

```
// Retrieve all posts that have at least one comment...
$posts = App\Post::has('comments')->get();
```

As theres no method like `notHas`, how can I find all posts that have no comments? 
(remembering that it's a `hasMany` relationship)

---

*Reference:*

**Querying Relationship Existence**

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a notHas() method as far as I'm aware, but finding records with a relationship count less than one usually satisfies this requirement:

```
$posts = App\Post::has('comments', '<', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 14):

Old topic but updated answer for those who came from Google like me. Nowadays you can just use doesntHave().

```
$posts = App\Post::doesntHave('comments')->get();
```

Reference:

**Querying Relationship Absence**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: Dominik Lenz you make my life easy, thanks,
this should be the best answer